# How to print Report / Documents in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing Invoice App, I want to generate formated invoice PDF/Document. I have tried iText.

What is the best way to generate formated PDF/DOC in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider sending plain text to a service, and make that service convert it to whatever you need.

If it's a relatively new printer, you could email it the docs to be printed.

Comment: it will work local at vendor mobile, with no internet, only mobile with printer.